# Bad Access when loading NSArray in init

Tags: ios, nsarray, init

I've got a class, called `Letter`. In the init method of Letter I am trying to load an Array of strings, so they can be used by other methods of that class.

I'm then instantiating an object based on the `Letter` class. I am expecting the `init` call to load the array, but instead am getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Letter.h

```
@interface Letter : NSObject
{
    NSArray *consonants;
}

-(BOOL)typeOfLetter:(NSString *)_letter;
```

Letter.m

```
#import "Letter.h"

@implementation Letter

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        consonants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"B",@"C",@"D",@"F",@"G",@"Ğ",@"H",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"P",@"R",@"S",@"Ş",@"T","@U",@"V",@"Y",@"Z",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"f",@"g",@"ğ",@"h",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"p",@"r",@"s",@"ş",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"z",nil];        
    }
    return self;
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BOOL retValue;

    Letter *letter = [[Letter alloc] init];
    retValue = [letter typeOfLetter:@"a"];

}
```

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: are you using ARC? does it crash here "[[Letter alloc] init]"?

Comment: If he used ARC it would throw a proper NSException instead of simply segfaulting.

Comment: I thought I selected ARC when creating the project. The compiler is the Apple LLVM Compiler 3.1. That makes it ARC, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to add a `@` before one of your strings
In your array you have this character `"@U"` you will have to change it to `@"U"`

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks mate. I'll have to look more carefully at those long lists of strings next time,

Comment: Thanks mate! That was it. I'll have to look at those long lists of strings more carefully in future. Cheers.